# The worker processcalls OpenSubKey but returns null by accessing Remote Registry service

Tags: iis-6, remote-registry

My web server is deployed in IIS 6. The web server starts the Remote Registry service in the remote machine successfully by creating a process to run some remote operation commands.

This first line runs successfully. But the second line returns null.

```
#1 RegistryKey remoteRegKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "139.24.185.27");

#2 RegistryKey targetKey = remoteRegKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\XXXX\XXXX\Config\Modality", true);
```

I tried to find the reason from MSDN. It tells only one case it would return null. The case is when the subkey does not exist.

- If it has not enough permission, it will throw exception. But the subkey really exists. I change another machine to debug my code with Visual Studio 2008. It can run two lines successfully.
- If it has enough permission, it should not only can open the LocalMachine, but also can open any of its subkeys.

I am quite confusing about this.

Answer (score 1):

The Wow6432 registry entry indicates that you're running a 64-bit version of Windows. The OS uses this key to present a separate view of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE for 32-bit applications that run on a 64-bit version of Windows. When a 32-bit application queries a value under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\\ subkey, the application reads from the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\\ subkey.